# Mysql Select Dynamic column (3 tables)

Tags: sql, mysql

I am looking for the SQL to do :

And thing about field list must be totally dynamic. I dont want to go change my SQL each time an admin add a field into the fields table.

```
Table content
    -------------
    CID
    text
    category

    CID | text | category
    ----------------------
    1   | ...  | apple
    2   | ...  | apple
    3   | ...  | apple

    Table fields
    -------------
    FID
    typename

    FID | typename
    ----------------
    1   | field1
    2   | field2
    3   | field3

    Table fields_value
    -------------
    CID
    FID
    value

    CID | FID | value
    -------------------
    1   | 1   | value1
    1   | 2   | value2
    1   | 3   | value3
    2   | 1   | value4
    2   | 2   | value5
    2   | 3   | value6
    3   | 1   | value7
    3   | 2   | value8
    3   | 3   | value9

    #####
    ---> ???? SELECT content.*,...dynamic field.* FROM content WHERE category = "apple" LIMIT 20

    RESULT I AM LOOKING FOR:
    -------------------
    CID | text | category | field1 | field2 | field3 
    -------------------------------------------------
    1   | ...  | apple    | value1 | value2 | value3
    2   | ...  | apple    | value4 | value5 | value6
    3   | ...  | apple    | value7 | value8 | value9
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843510/database-eav-model-record-listing-as-per-search

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want with mysql (have dynamically named columns).  The closest you can do is

```
SELECT CID, text, category, typename, value
  FROM content JOIN fields_value JOIN fields
  WHERE content.CID = fields_value.CID AND fields_value.FID = fields.FID
```

Which will give you

```
CID | text | category | typename | value
 1  | ...  | apple    | field1   | value1
 1  | ...  | apple    | field2   | value2
 1  | ...  | apple    | field3   | value3
 2  | ...  | apple    | field1   | value4
 2  | ...  | apple    | field2   | value5
 2  | ...  | apple    | field3   | value6
 3  | ...  | apple    | field1   | value7
 3  | ...  | apple    | field2   | value8
 3  | ...  | apple    | field3   | value9
```

Of course, you could make a table dynamically by loading the `fields` table and building a `CREATE TABLE` command with the fields you want, then populate it from your `fields_value` table, but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: hi. ty for the answer. but I found a way. I must know first the field list. So I make a select on the fields table before. After in php I built a LEFT JOIN and a field select for each fields.